# Creating an OCX control in C#

Tags: c#, mfc, ocx

What are the steps which needs to be followed to create an OCX controls using C#. Can you give me  sample coddes for the same . I need to use this control in MFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreateActiveXDotNet.aspx) addresses your needs, including code and step-by-step guide.